# How to solve non-linear ODE $(v')^2+v'-\frac{v}{u}=0?$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving the certain problem,  I obtained non-differential equation
$(v')^2+v'-\frac{v}{u}=0,$ $v$ is function of $u.$ I'm not very familiar with differential equations, so I'm wondering is this to hard to solve or there is a certain method for solving it.

Comment: I guess this one can be called *ugly*.

Comment: Seems to be another form of d'Alembert's equation. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(v%27)%5E2+%2B+v%27+%3D+v%2Fu

Comment: A one easy solution is the constant solution: $v(u)=0$, but I guess you are not asking for that

Comment: almost no nonlinear differential equation are simple. do you need to solve this ODE for the problem? because i don't think that someone that is not very familiar with differential equations need to know how to do this

Comment: @Efe : The ODE is solvable. I could give you the solution, but it is a big analytical calculus which I am reluctant to type. May be, it could be simpler to start from the initial problem itself, instead of an intermediate result which possibly complicates instead of simplifies. Would you like to post the initial wording ?

Comment: I'm reparameterizing certain ruled surface doing the reparametrization of a base curve. The "new" base curve is a solution of a non-linear differential equation. I done all the theory, now I'm trying to give some examples, better I skip it.

Comment: In fact the difficulty was coming from the handling of some special functions involved all along. By luck, a much simpler approach avoids a lot of those difficulties. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\frac{dv}{du}\right)^2+\frac{dv}{du}-\frac{v}{u}=0 \tag 1$$
The ODE is homogeneous. So, the convenient change of is :

$v(u)=uy(u) \quad\to\quad\frac{dv}{du}=y+u\frac{dy}{du} \quad\to\quad \left(y+u\frac{dy}{du}\right)^2+y+u\frac{dy}{du}-y=0$
$$\left(y+u\frac{dy}{du}\right)^2+u\frac{dy}{du}=0$$
Let $\quad u=e^x \quad\to\quad u\frac{dy}{du}=\frac{dy}{dx} $
$$\left(y+\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
This ODE is separable : $\quad \left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2+(2y+1)\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2=0$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac12\left(2y+1 \pm\sqrt{4y+1}\right)$$
$$x=\int \frac{2dy}{2y+1 \pm\sqrt{4y+1}}$$
The next calculus has to be done two times distinctly, one with sign $+$ , one with sign $-$.

$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{4y+1} }{2y+1\pm\sqrt{4y+1}}\left(1+\left(1\pm\sqrt{4y+1}\right)\ln\left( 1\pm\sqrt{4y+1}\right) \right)+c$$
Let $\quad t=1\pm\sqrt{4y+1}\quad\to\quad y=\frac{t(t-2)}{4}\quad$ which leads in both cases to the same result :
$$x=\frac{2 }{t}+\ln(t^2)+c$$
$u=e^x=Ct^2e^{2/t}$

$v=yu=\frac{t(t-2)}{4}Ct^2e^{2/t} =\frac{C}{4}t^3(t-2)e^{2/t}$

The solution of Eq.$(1)$ is obtained on parametric form :

$$\begin{cases}
u=Ct^2e^{2/t}\\
v=\frac{C}{4}t^3(t-2)e^{2/t}
\end{cases}$$

The explicit form $v(u)$ cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. A special function is required : The Lambert W function.

$u=Ct^2e^{2/t} \quad\to\quad t= -\frac{1}{W\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{C}{u}}\right)}$
$$v(u)=-\frac{C}{4}\left(\frac{1}{W\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{C}{u}}\right)}\right)^3\left(-\frac{1}{W\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{C}{u}}\right)}-2\right)\exp\left(-2W\left(\pm\sqrt{\frac{C}{u}}\right) \right)$$